# Defining a callback function in the definition itself

Tags: javascript, angular, blob, gojs

I have this download function which is doing a callback to "downloadCallback".

I want the downloadCallback function to be defined inside the download function itself. How can I do that?

Here is the download() function:

```
 download() {
    let blob = this.diagram.makeImageData({ background: "white", returnType: "blob", callback: <any>this.downloadCallback
  })
};
```

Here is the downloadCallback function:

```
downloadCallback(blob : any) : void {
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {            
      var imageDataUrl = reader.result;
      var imgWidth = imageDataUrl.width;
      var imgHeight = imageDataUrl.height; 
      let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); 
      var position = 0;
      pdf.setFontSize(30);
      pdf.text("Diagram", 100, 20, 'center');
      pdf.addImage(imageDataUrl, 'PNG', 0, 25, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);  
      pdf.save('Diagram.pdf');
      console.log(imageDataUrl);  
    };
   reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
  }
```

I am using GoJS By the way. What I am trying to do is to download a graph in the form of PDF.

Comment: _How can I do that?_ Did you try to do it? Because you can actually declare a function almost anywhere.

Comment: I know that and I tried doing that also, using arrow functions as well, but it is not working in this very specific case. like, callback: () =>{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you define your function before trying to use it, like so:

```
download() {
    // Create the function
    const downloadCallback = (): void => {
      console.log("Test");
    }

    // Use it
    let blob = this.diagram.makeImageData({ background: "white", returnType: "blob", callback: <any>downloadCallback});  
}
```

Comment: Should I define the function in the donwload function itself, because this seems to not working for me.

Comment: @s4tr2 Yes, it should be inside the download function, and at the top of the download function. When you try to call it, make sure you **not** using `this.downloadCallback`, it should just be `downloadCallback`

Comment: @s4tr2 Good stuff, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the downloadCallback() inside the download() function and remove this from the function call:

```js
download() {
    let blob = this.diagram.makeImageData({ background: "white", returnType: "blob", callback: <any>downloadCallback
  });
  
  downloadCallback(blob : any) : void {
    // ...
  }
};
```

Should work with no problems, I didn't test it though

Comment: Cannot find downloadCallback .

Comment: Sorry, @user184994's answer should be the correct one.

Comment: It needs to be defined before usage. Or changed to `var  downloadCallback = function(blob : any) : void { ... }`. Usage of `var` enables hoisting.

Comment: @connexo While `var` *does* enable hoisting, that only effects the context of the variable, *not* where its defined. For this reason, the variable would be accessible, but it would still be undefined.